# XSLT copy all and replace on conditions

Tags: xml, xslt

I need an XSLT transform that copies the whole input document to the output document, inserting a specific element with a default value if the input document does not contain that element.

Specifically, I want to transform input XML of this general form

```
<Begin>
    <tag1>a</tag1>
    <tag2>b</tag2>
</Begin>
```

to itself, but if the input has no `/Begin/tag1` then I want to provide one.  That is, I want to transform

```
<Begin>
    <tag2>c</tag2>
</Begin>
```

to

```
<Begin>
    <tag1>x</tag1>
    <tag2>c</tag2>
</Begin>
```

This is my my current XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It copies the whole input document, but it does not provide for supplying a default `<tag1>` element.  I cannot use `<xsl:choose>` inside the template in that stylesheet, as it will insert a `<tag1>` into ever element that does not have one, and I cannot place a `choose` *after* the template as it's not valid. How can I provide a default `<tag1>` element *only* for the `<Begin>` element?

Comment: What you describe makes little sense.  Why do you need specifically to do this by selecting `node()|@*` in an `apply-templates`?  Is the output of the transform supposed to depend on anything at all other than whether `/Begin/tag1` is present?  What is the transform actually "copy[ing]" from the source document?

Comment: I want to do it specifically by using node()|@* because i have been trying to do that for the past 2 hours :) :P Anyways, if you have any other way to do it, i will be happy to see it as well. No the output is not supposed to depend on anything other than whether /Begin/tag1 is present.

Comment: I want to copy all the elements in the source to the target. So I guess node()|@* is the only way to do it? Isn't it?

Comment: You are being inconsistent.  If you want to copy all the elements from input to output then the output depends on *all the elements in the input*.  You previously said that it depends only on whether `/Begin/tag1` exists.

Comment: Look, copying all the elements is one part of the problem.. the second part is changing the value if /Begin/tag1 exists or not. Hope this makes it clear

Comment: No, it doesn't quite.  Am I to understand, then, that the example outputs are incorrect in presenting different content for the `<tag2>` element than is present in the example input?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141364/discussion-between-chandeep-and-john-bollinger).

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect the clarifications you provided in comments and chat.  If I've still misunderstood then please make any other needed changes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger:  Couldn't be more perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you cannot put an `<xsl:choose>` element outside a template.  XSL operates by transforming nodes of the input document; you can express the details of the transformation only in terms of how specific nodes are transformed -- i.e. via templates.

Moreover, it is usually more natural to express alternatives by providing alternative templates or `select` expressions than by using logical elements such as `<xsl:choose>` of `<xsl:if>` inside templates.

In this case you have two alternatives to consider:

1. The input document's `/Begin` element has a `tag1` child
2. The input document's `/Begin` element does not have a `tag1` child

In the first case, you don't need to do anything special -- the identity transform you've already written will do the right thing.  All you need, then, is an appropriate template to handle the latter alternative.  As long as it has higher priority than the identity transform, it will be used for the `Begin` element instead of the identity transform, wherever it applies.

For example,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Begin[count(tag1) = 0]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <tag1>x</tag1>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the added template, which applies (only) to `Begin` elements that have no `<tag1>` child.  It copies the whole element and its child nodes, but also inserts a `<tag1>`.

Comment: Thanks John. That definitely helps. I am just trying to figure out how this code will change when i more number of elements to insert and that too in a specific order i.e. i want tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5 etc to come in output. But tag2 and tag4 may not be present in the input. I won;t be able to use copy in that case because the sequence will change.

Comment: That's quite a different question, @Chandeep, and you should pose it as one.  A different approach is required if you want to provide default elements for *multiple* children, and / or to reorder the children.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351071/xslt-copy-all-and-insert-missing-in-a-specific-order

Answer (score 1):

You can add a template that matches `Begin` if it has no `tag1` and inserts the `tag1`. Note here that this works for your very simple example, but if you have a more complex case with a lot of elements or multiple elements to insert, then the solution could become more complex.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Begin[not(tag1)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <tag1>x</tag1>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What happens if I have more number of elements to insert? How should I handle in that case?