# XSLT copy all and insert missing in a specific order

Tags: xml, xslt

I need an XSLT transform that copies the whole input document to the output document, inserting elements in a specific order.

Specifically, I want to transform input XML of this general form

```
<Begin>
    <tag1>a</tag1>
    <tag2>b</tag2>
    <tag3>c</tag3>
    <tag4>d</tag4>
    <tag5>e</tag5>
</Begin>
```

to itself, but if the input has no `/Begin/tag1` or `/Begin/tag4`then I want to provide one in the order given above.  That is, I want to transform

```
<Begin>
    <tag2>b</tag2>
    <tag3>c</tag3>
    <tag5>e</tag5>
</Begin>
```

to

```
<Begin>
    <tag1>a</tag1>
    <tag2>b</tag2>
    <tag3>c</tag3>
    <tag4>d</tag4>
    <tag5>e</tag5>
</Begin>
```

I asked a related question to this [XSLT copy all and replace on conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324263/xslt-copy-all-and-replace-on-conditions/43325798#43325798) with a thought of extrapolating the solution to big number of nodes but I am unable to figure the solution to the above problem.

Comment: Is it only `tag1` and `tag4` children for which you want the transform to provide default values, or could it, perhaps, be the others as well?

Comment: it can be others as well.. Its just an example with tag1 and tag4

Comment: Could `<Begin>` have any other child nodes that need to be copied (e.g. non-whitespace text nodes or elements other than the `tagN`s)?

Comment: ... or comment nodes, or processing instruction nodes, *etc*..

Comment: no.. no comment nodes or any white space nodes.. only tagN's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are now asking is doable, but it does not afford quite as tidy a solution as does your previous question.  Nevertheless, it is doable.

The approach that seems cleanest to me involves using `<xsl:choose>`, which in your previous question you remarked you had not been able to apply as specifically as you wanted.  As is usually the case with XSL, the key is to properly select the nodes to which each template applies.  You don't want to add default children to *every* node, but rather only to `<Begin>` nodes.  You might thus do this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- by default, all nodes and attributes are copied verbatim to the output -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Begin elements are transformed differently: -->
  <xsl:template match="Begin">
    <!-- the element itself is copied, along with its attributes, if any -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />

      <!-- each child, tag1 ... tagN, is copied if present or inserted
           if absent.  A separate choice must be made for each. -->
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="tag1">
          <!-- will apply the identity transform, because there is no other
               template that matches: -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="tag1" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <tag1>x1</tag1>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>

      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="tag2">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="tag2" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <tag2>x2</tag2>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>

      <!-- ... the same for tag3, tag4, tag5 ... -->

      <!-- no provision is herein made for any child nodes of Begin other than
           attributes and child elements tag1 ... tag5 -->
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your choose/otherwise constructs can be reduced to `<xsl:apply-templates select="tagX" />` + `<xsl:if test="not(tagX)">...</xsl:if>` - two lines instead of 8 per case.

Comment: Hi @john- This works like a charm.. Can you tell me how <apply-templates select="node()" and <apply-templates select=@* differ?

Comment: You are right, @Tomalak, but I opted for `<xsl:choose>` because in this case, I think the slight increase in template size is offset by improved clarity.  YMMV.

Comment: Also, I don't think the first copy is required - <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

Saying this because as soon as the Begin template starts, everything is being handled in that.. the purpose of the above copy code was to avoid copying each and every node seperatey which in the above answer we are doing. Agreed?

Comment: Isn't there any way that I can avoid the copying of some nodes which i know won't be having any choice and needs to be copied as it is in the output keeping the sequence intact?

Comment: @Chandeep, the initial identity transform *is* required.  It's the only one that applies to the tagN elements when they initially exist and need to be copied.  If you like, try removing it, and see what happens.

Comment: I tried doing that.. and it works actually.. if I only keep the begin template match and apply templates inside it, I am able to get what i want.

Comment: @Chandeep, I find that doubtful.  When *I* remove the identity transform from the stylesheet and apply the result to a document, only the default elements corresponding to missing tagN elements appear in the result `<Begin>` element.  There aren't any elements at all in the output corresponding to the tagN nodes that were present in the input.

Comment: @Chandeep, if --contrary to your previous assertion -- there are some of the tagN that you are confident will be present in the input document, so that you don't need to worry about providing defaults, or if there are other nodes you need to copy, then you can put in bare `<xsl:apply-templates>` elements in the appropriate places, selecting the appropriate elements, instead of using `<xsl:choose>` constructs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141483/discussion-between-chandeep-and-john-bollinger).